# Flask and ssh2 python not port forwading on docker image

Tags: python, docker

so I do have the next code, which is a Flask app, and it runs on a Raspberry inside a docker container with NginX and Uwsgi.
I need to be able to connect to local ssh and also to get the correct MAC address of the Raspberry.

```
import socket
import time
import pwd
import os
from ssh2.session import Session
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

usernameSSH = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name
passwordSSH = "password"
host = 'localhost'  # the specified host for the SSH

@app.route("/")
def hello():
 return gma() #get mac address of the device

@app.route("/ssh") #This is the connection to ssh
def welcome():
 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 sock.connect((host, 22))

 session = Session()
 session.handshake(sock)
 session.userauth_password(usernameSSH, passwordSSH)
 channel = session.open_session()

 channel.shell()
 channel.write("ifconfig\n")
 time.sleep(2)
 size, data = channel.read()
 channel.close()
 return data.decode("utf-8")

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(threaded=True)
```

So. If I run my docker image like this:

> docker run -p 3134:80 dockapp

I'm able to connect with the external IP and port. But the mac address that I get on external IP:port/ it's wrong, it's the mac address of the container. Also, I get auth error when trying to connect to ssh.

If I run my image like this:

> sudo docker run -p 3134:80 --network=host dockapp

I'm able to reach the API only by typing the local address of the RaspBerry but I do get the correct MAC Addres but still I'm not able to connect to local SSH and I get an authError. The program is running fine without docker. Any solutions ?

Also, adding host="0.0.0.0" to the Flask App hasn't helped at all

DockerFile:

```
FROM cseelye/rpi-nginx-uwsgi-flask
MAINTAINER Carl Seelye <cseelye@gmail.com>


RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake libssl-dev

COPY exampleapp /app
RUN pip install -U -r /app/requirements.txt
```

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: @larsks I have added it